# jQuery posts error text when posting with ajax

Tags: php, jquery

When I'm posting via ajax I'm sometimes getting extra characters posted for example.  If the text passed though ajax yo a php $_POST I end up getting:

> This is my messagejQuery127638276487364873268_374632874687326487

99% of the time posts pass though fine... I'm unsure how to capture and remove this error as it only happens some of the time.

```
// this is the ajax that we need to post the footprint to the wall.
$('#submitbutton').click(function () {
    var footPrint = $('#footPrint').val();
            var goUserId = '1';
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/scripts/ajax-ProfileObjects.php',
       data: 'do=leave_footprint&footPrint=' + footPrint + '&ref=' + goUserId + '&json=1',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){

            var textError = data.error;
            var textAction = data.action;
            var textList = data.list;

            if (textError == 'post_twice' || textError =='footprint_empty' || textError == 'login_req') {
            // display the error.

            } else {
            // lets fade out the item and update the page.

            }

     });

return false; });
```

Comment: You'll need to post your code or an example in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out through a process of elimination that the error was being caused by invalid data being passed to the query string.

**The line:**

```
data: 'do=leave_footprint&footPrint=' + footPrint + '&ref=' + goUserId + '&json=1',
```

I noticed that the footPrint variable would always break the script if '??' was passed.  A number of members when asking a question would use a '??' when and not a single '?'

By wrapping the footPrint var in encodeURIComponent() I can send all the text though to the PHP script without breaking the URL string.

**New Line:**

```
 data: 'do=leave_footprint&footPrint=' + encodeURIComponent(footPrint) + '&ref=' + goUserId + '&json=1',
```

This solution has worked for me... questions comments and suggestions still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try set cache to false. From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

cache Boolean
Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my code and will see if any posts show up.  If it's a cache problem should I also set the PHP file no not cache as well?

Comment: @Philip I guess you don't need to put any php header() staff. _=[TIMESTAMP] param is used for this purpose